# Display Numeric OSK

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, on-screen-keyboard

I know that to show OSK, all I have to is simply execute `osk.exe`.  What I want to implement further is to use it in its numeric form:

[image]

E.g. I want to save one mouse click for the user.

Target OS is windows 10.

P.S. is there any other way to display the OSK?

Comment: OSK does not have an option that you are looking for.  You will likely have to use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) to manually enable the desired display form after OSK is running

Comment: That appears to be tabtip.exe not osk.exe btw

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770670/how-do-i-control-the-text-input-panel-programmatically-tabtip-exe-in-windows-v and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157885/mfc-on-screen-keyboard-when-focusing-editable-control