# C++ 32 bit application trying to use 64bit MFC DLLs

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I'm migrating a large C++ application from Visual Studio 6 into VS2013. I've built the exe's and DLL's. I've worked through a number of issues and I'm able to start the program. Right after the program started, it stops running. After using Dependency Walker, I believe the problem is that my 32 bit EXEs and DLLs are trying to use the 64bit version of the MFC DLLs. Here's a screen shot:

[image]

My understanding is that 32bit applications should automatically use the DLLs located in C:\Windows\SysWow64 directory; but that doesn't seem to be happening here.

I've looked in the project settings for something obvious which might fix this, but I haven't found anything. I'm wondering if any of you have had this problem, and if so, what did you do to solve it?

Thanks for your help!

Regards,
Mike

Comment: DependencyWalker used to be a trustworthy tool, in it's time. Today, it gets confused more often than not. If your application does get off the ground, it cannot be statically linked against a DLL with the wrong bitness. Don't trust DependencyWalker. Use another tool to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @IInspectable What tool?

Comment: You can use Process Monitor (free download from Microsoft)  to see what files are trying to be loaded.  If you run under the debugger, you can see what files are being loaded in your modules list.

Comment: @sergiol: [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) can be used to follow, where the system is looking for DLLs, and which ones. There are other tools out there. As explained, though, I doubt that this is a bitness-mismatch issue.

Comment: See point 4) of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14157885/383779 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119204/application-gives-error-only-on-64-bit-version

Comment: Ok guys, thank you all very much for these ideas and links...Once more into the breach!

Comment: Please see my 2nd post on this issue. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank IInspectable for pointing out problems with Process Monitor. I didn't find a specific replacement tool for PM, but I used Visual Studio's Debug->Windows->Modules dialog tool. I attached the debugger to the executable and I saw this:
[image]

This show that my initial thought (that my DLLs are pointing to the wrong system directory) was incorrect.  This is a relief!

Of'course I'm back to square one with this problem, but at least I'm not wasting time following a red herring.

Thank you all for your help! I appreciate it.

Sincerely,
Mike